# Rails find_or_create method AND update record attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does Rails find_or_create_by() also update a records attributes if the record is found. If not, is there a simple way to find_or_create a record, and if the record already exists; to update the records attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want something that does a `create_or_update_by`,
which could be these two steps:

```
my_app_class = ClassName.find_or_initialize_by_name(last_name, first_name).update_attributes
({
   :last_name => self.last_name,
   :first_name => self.first_name,
})
```

Comment: Im trying to accomplish this in a rake task, with data being parsed from a csv file. Each record is created successfully, however existing records are not being updated.

Comment: I would consider posting that question along with the setup details of your rake task as a separate question.